# php display array data in multiple columns by using ceil function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

For example, I have a array with 8 data. I want to display in this format

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
======            
 1  2 
 3  4 
 5  6 
 7  8 
=====
```

OR array with 11 data

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
=========
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11  
=========
```

Not sure which part i got wrong. Here is my code

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$c = ceil(count($a)/2);

echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i<$c;$i++){
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>'.$a[$i].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$a[$i+1].'</td>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

However, my data display in this way instead

```
======            
 1  2 
 2  3 
 3  4 
 4  5 
=====
```

Basically, I want to display my data from mysql in this format. But before that, I need to test out the ceil function and see if its working. Anyone knows whats wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 cels per row you need to calculate the actual index. Also don't forget to close the `<tr>`

```
for($i=0; $i<$c;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$a[$i * 2].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$a[$i * 2 + 1].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Here is a full example of a cleaner solution:

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$cols = 2;
$c = ceil(count($a) / $cols);

echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
        $value = isset($a[$i * $cols + $col]) ? $a[$i * $cols + $col] : '';
        echo '<td>'. $value .'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it only displays 1,2,3,4.  Staring from 5 to 8 didn't list out

Comment: @Dimitri L. your code works after modified. However, If my array with 9 data, it shows this error -> Notice: Undefined offset: 9     . Looks like the error due to the no.9 data. so that means your code works with even number. If odd number, it will shows offset error

Comment: @gosulove obviously it is showing a notice, since you have no if condition to check if the index exists. I added an extended code sample for you.

Comment: @DimitriL. no, your coding doesn't list out all the data. Please check . thx

Comment: I mixed up the variables, now it should work as intended

Answer (score 1):

If you increase it manually you have to skip 1 loop every time.

```
$a    = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
$size = sizeof($a);

/* Your magic method to determine the total table cols.
*/
$cols = 3;
#$cols = 2;

echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i+=$cols){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++){
      if($i+$c >= $size){
        break;
      }

      echo '<td>'.$a[$i+$c].'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I've used the method of math to determine if it should print or not because it is faster. However, if you have empty indexes in the array you might want to use the `isset()` method as the whole code in the inner for loop.

```
if(isset($a[$i+$c])){
  echo '<td>'.$a[$i+$c].'</td>';
}
```

Comment: Mine is array, does your working manage to list out all the data from an array in this way?

Comment: it works fine for 2 column data.  What if I want to display in 3 columns or 4 columns? Your matter still work If not using ceil ?

Comment: @gosulove Updated the code to not use `ceil()` altogether, making the code a whole lot easier to read as well.

Comment: Thx for your effort